# CakePHP 2.x deleting HABTM data when dependent is true

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, has-and-belongs-to-many

I Have a question regarding CakePHP, suppose I have two Model `Doctor` and `Degree`, `Doctor is HABTM relation with Degree` and vice-versa.
Now I set the **dependency** **true**, so my question is what would be deleted if I delete any one of following by id, only dependency deleted (i.e. data from DegreesDoctor Model) or related HABTM data as well?
(means on deleting doctor, associated degree also get deleted?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See, if you delete `Doctor` record then `Doctor` Record will be definitely deleted .

Also at the same time `Mapping` : Courses that Doctor is related to is also deleted.

In short : Record from `doctors` table And associated record for That `doctor_id` in table `degreesdoctors` also get deleted.

Same will occur if u delete Degree record.

Comment: so the degree record will not be deleted(on deleting doctor)?

Comment: @ashishTripathi , No , See think logical .In degrees table there are 3 degrees : `BHMS`,`BAMS` & `MBBS` , There are 1000 doctors .Dr.A is BHMS so His mapping is in `degreesdoctors` table . Also many doctors are having BHMS degree mapping,So if i delete Dr.A , Do u want Degree `BHMS` deleted from `degrees` table ????? Then mapping done for BHMS primary key : id,other Doctors will be pointing to BHMS in mapping table , But assume , BHMS is deleted from degrees ,then id will point to record in degrees Which is deleted.

Comment: There is no "dependent" parameter on hasAndBelongsToMany relations in CakePHP 2.x

Answer (score 0):

If you set dependant as true it will delete all dependant data also.

An extract from the cakePHP documentation;

**Dependent : When the dependent key is set to true, and the model’s delete() method is called with the cascade parameter set to true, associated model records are also deleted. In this case, we set it true so that deleting a User will also delete her associated Profile.**

Source: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

Comment: There is no "dependent" parameter on hasAndBelongsToMany relations in CakePHP 2.x